# Would replacing sourced bash functions with executables decrease startup time

Tags: startup, bashrc, profile, dot-files

A typical bash setup, `source`es additional dotfiles on startup which obviously increases the startup time.

Is there an be any benefit of moving the contents of a function to its own executable file?

## Current setup

### ~/.bashrc

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f ~/.bash_functions ]; then . ~/.bash_functions; fi
```

### ~/.bash_functions

```
#!/bin/sh
function_one(){}
function_two(){}
....
```

## Suggested Setup

### ~/.bashrc

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.bash_functions/bin"
```

- ~/

  - .bash_functions/

    - bin/

      - function_one
      - function_two

Answer (score 2):

Actually, executing a script file will spawn a new shell process while sourcing a script doesn't, so your premise is wrong. Even if it wasn't:

1) The suggested setup won't work because the functions won't be visible outside the newly spawned shell.

2) The difference between execution time of a sourced script and an executable script is negligible.

3) The suggested setup will end up in having *more* executed files.

Shell scripts (which are interpreted) are anyway made for clarity and practicality and not for high performances such as compiled C programs. What basically you're trying to do here (in the wrong way!) is to tune a donkey cart.

Comment: What newly spawned shell are you talking about?

Comment: @Barmar The scripts that would be in the proposed `~/.bash_functions/bin`.

Comment: I didn't think there would be functions inside the scripts, the scripts would replace the functions. I.e. the contents of each script would be the body of the corresponding function. The only problem would be if a function wants to change the shell environment.